# Show that $3n^2 - n+4$ is $O(n^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

From the definition of big oh: We say that "$f(n)$ is big oh $g(n)$" if there exists an integer $n_0$ and a constant $c>0$ such that for all integers $n\geq n_0$, $f(n)\leq cg(n)$.

Substituting the equation we have:

$$3n^2 - n+4\leq cn^2$$

Since I can choose $c$ to be, say, $5000$ and $n$ to be $1$, does that mean I have proven it is $O(n^2)$ because the righthand side will be larger?

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with complex analysis.

Answer (score 2):

For $n>1$ you have
$$
0<3n^2 - n + 4 \le 3n^2 +n^2 = 4n^2
$$

Comment: Sorry I don't get what that is saying.

Comment: this is an explicit $O()$.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia:

> Big O notation describes the limiting behaviour of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity, usually in terms of simpler functions.

So, basically, Big O notation provides an upper bound on the value of the function as it approaches large values of the parameter. Mathematically, $f(n)=O(n^2)$ is the equivalent of saying that $$|f(n)|\leq M|n^2|$$ for $n>n_0$, choosing $M$ and $n_0$ as appropriate.

For example,
$$f(n)=3n^2-n+4$$
$$f(n)=O(n^2)$$
Therefore we can say that
$$|3n^2-n+4|\leq M|n^2|$$
If $M=8$ and $n_0=1$ respectively.

Why these values? Well, for $n>1$
$$|3n^2-n+4|\leq 3n^2 +|n|+4 \leq 3n^2+n^2+4n^2 = 8n^2$$
Thus $$f(n) \leq 8n^2$$
or $$f(n)=O(n^2)$$

Comment: Why did you change the minus to a plus in $3n^2+\vert n\vert+4$ and where did the $\vert\vert$ around $n$ come from? Also, how did you get $3n^2+n^2+4n^2$??

Comment: Okay, the general idea is that the expression on the right hand side has to be bigger than that on the left, as well as being all of the same power of $n$. The minus changes to a plus so as to ensure that the RHS is larger. All of the powers are increased to $n^2$ so as to ensure that the RHS is bigger for all $n>n_0$. As for the || around the $n$, I suppose that they don't have to be there in this case, since $n_0>0$, but it is good practice for situations where $n_0<0$.

Comment: In fact, look at the first example on this article: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation